# JUnit test not loading properties file, but runtime code works correctly

Tags: spring, junit, properties, annotations

I have some production code that works correctly. But the JUnit test I wrote for it does not load the testing properties file and fails.

Googled for examples of how to load test properties. None of the answers helped.

The testing properties file, stored in src/test/resources, is:

```
#Generated by Git-Commit-Id-Plugin
#Sat Aug 31 08:34:13 EDT 2019
build-details.branch=feature/issue-189
build-details.build.time=20190831083412
build-details.build.version=0.4.9
build-details.commit.id=3cbdbaee42d2b6bde342fce32ecd61905d8d12d4
build-details.commit.time=20190831083101
```

The JUnit test is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:/build-details.properties"})
public class DetailsServiceTest {
    private static final String TEST_BRANCH = "feature/issue-532";
    private static final String TEST_BUILD_TIME = "20190831083412";
    private static final String TEST_BUILD_VERSION = "0.4.9";
    private static final String TEST_COMMIT_ID = "3cbdbaee42d2b6bde342fce32ecd61905d8d12d4";
    private static final String TEST_COMMIT_TIME = "20190831083101";

    @InjectMocks private DetailsService detailsService;
    @Test
    public void testGetDetails() {
        final BuildDetails result = detailsService.getBuildDetails();

        assertNotNull(result);

        assertEquals(TEST_BRANCH,
                     result.getBranch());
        assertEquals(TEST_BUILD_TIME,
                     result.getBuildTime());
        assertEquals(TEST_BUILD_VERSION,
                     result.getBuildVersion());
        assertEquals(TEST_COMMIT_ID,
                     result.getCommitId());
        assertEquals(TEST_COMMIT_TIME,
                     result.getCommitTime());
    }
}
```

And the service being tested is:

```
@Service
@PropertySource({"classpath:/build-details.properties"})
public class DetailsService {
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${build-details.branch") private String branch;
    @Value("${build-details.build.time}") private String buildTime;
    @Value("${build-details.build.version}") private String buildVersion;
    @Value("${build-details.commit.id}") private String commitId;
    @Value("${build-details.commit.time}") private String commitTime;

    public BuildDetails getBuildDetails() {
        final BuildDetails result = new BuildDetails();

        result.setBranch(branch);
        result.setBuildTime(buildTime);
        result.setBuildVersion(buildTime);
        result.setCommitId(commitId);
        result.setCommitTime(commitTime);

        return result;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, the service works as expected. When I run the service and query it, I'm getting back:

```
{"branch":"${build-details.branch","buildTime":"20190831112809","buildVersion":"20190831112809","commitId":"6e709c0401627149505c91348f960e585fc5f24b","commitTime":"20190831103506"}
```

(values reflecting the live build).

But when I run the unit test, all of the field values are consistently null.

Answer (score 1):

Using the MockitoJUnitRunner doesn't load the Spring context in the test, so those value annotations aren't getting the values injected.  You could try switching to a different runner that loads the spring context to have spring inject those values from your test properties file.

Try using the  Spring runner to see if that helps.  Instead of using `@InjectMocks` you can use `@Autowired` to get the bean from spring which should have the values from the test properties file.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:/build-details.properties"})
public class DetailsServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private DetailsService detailsService;

//... 

}
```

Also, it looks like you're missing a closing curly brace on one of the `@Value` annotations and a setter is using the build time.   Guessing it should be:

```java
    @Value("${build-details.branch}") private String branch;

    // ...

    result.setBuildVersion(buildVersion); // instead of buildTime
```

Comment: Taking your advice, and converting the test to use SpringRunner rather than Mockito, and having the service autowired instead of using injectmock, worked! TY very much for the reply!